# How do I enable multimode emacs to program PHP without messing up my indents?

Tags: php, emacs

Whenever I indent `HTML` in `PHP` mode, `emacs (22.1.1, basic install on Redaht Linux over Putty-SSH)` pops up a frame and tells me to get `MUMODE` or `somesuch` extra add-on.  I installed `PHP` Mode without a big hassle, but I don't know how to get this multi-mode rolling.

---

I'd like to know 2 things

```
How to install and configure multi-mode
How to disable pop-ups in Emacs
```

Comment: Can you give more specific instructions as to how to reproduce this?  I'm not sure what you mean by pop-up, and I can edit PH/HTML files without any such hassle here.

Comment: Open a PHP file laden with HTML Markeup, try indenting the HTML, eventually you'll get a second window telling you how badly it fails and launches a second window frame saying that you should get MuMaMo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running emacs 22, you should just be able to run:

```
M-x nxhtml-mumamo
```

when editing an html document.  You might want to add it to your auto-mode-alist to get it to automatically load for html docs.  See here for more info:

http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/MuMaMo
http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/PhpMode

Comment: Thanks! This worked great for windows, oddly enough. MuMaMo seems super slow through my SSH connection though.

Answer (score 1):

web-mode.el is available on http://web-mode.org
This major mode is designed to edit html php templates (with JS and CSS)
Add those two lines in your `.emacs`

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml$" . web-mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

multi-mode and html-php-mode can be found here : http://www.loveshack.ukfsn.org/emacs/

It can be initialized with:

```
(require 'html-php)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . html-php-mode))
```